# Calculated column, formula to count how much time left before deadline

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have 2013 list (on premises) and I have a column "Deadline date". I need to create a calculated formula which 30, 60 and 90 days before will show such text, 30, 60 or 90 days left before deadline.

Could you please help me to write a formula or share any instruction or similar post?

Comment: Have you tried Emily's reply? Does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two columns, a date and time column named Deadline date, a calculated column named cal.

=if([Deadline date]-Today()=30, CONCATENATE("30","-",TEXT([Deadline date],"yyyy-mm-dd")), if([Deadline date]-Today()=60, CONCATENATE("60","-",TEXT([Deadline date],"yyyy-mm-dd")), if([Deadline date]-Today()=90,CONCATENATE("90","-",TEXT([Deadline date],"yyyy-mm-dd")),"")))

Result:

[image]